# Toggle and communicate between two Windows forms in Visual C#?

Tags: c#

I have two forms in my Windows Form Application, a main and a login info form.
[image: main form][image: login form]

The main form has a button which opens the login info form on being clicked. The login info form gets displayed as a new form on the main window with the main window also being visible in background while the user enters login info. If the login info is correct the login form should close while the main form should display the string "Welcome" and the correct username from login form. Now the issue is that after entering the correct login info on the login form and clicking the Login button, a new window of the main form appears with the previous main form also running as shown in the figure.[image].

How can I make the previous instance of main form close and get the correct text displayed? Any help is appreciated.

I am using the following codes for creating and opening the main and the login info forms.

Code snippet of main form:

```
public partial class Main_Form : Form
{
    private string u_name = "";
    public Main_Form(string username)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        u_name = username;

        label1.Text = label1.Text + " " + u_name;
    }

    private void Loginbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form Form2 = new login_Form();

        Form2.ShowDialog();  
                    
    }
}
```

Code snippet of login form:

```
public partial class login_Form : Form
{
    public static string username = "";
    public login_Form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox_Login.Text == "Admin" && textBox_Password.Text == "123")
        {
            this.Hide();

            username = textBox_Login.Text;

            Form Form1 = new Main_Form(username);                              

            Form1.ShowDialog();                
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Username and/or Password Again!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Form Form1 = new Main_Form` create a new instance of Main_Form... it is not the same as the one which is already open... that's why you are seeing two Main_Form after Login Click...

Comment: I understand, what is the solution to activating the same Main_Form instead of creating a new instance?

Comment: Did the below answer help you?

Comment: Yes will definitely try this out and select as the solution if it works as intended!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have 2 instances of MainForm, just use one and update as required.
In your mainform you should call the LoginForm and check the `DialogResult` (I will explain this later).

So here, if you get an OK result it means the Login worked, otherwise the user cancelled.

So in MainForm change the constructor to be empty and remove the `u_name` parameter

```
public Main_Form()
{
   ....
}


private void Loginbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form Form2 = new login_Form();   
    if(Form2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)   //We call LoginForm and wait for a Result
    {
         //Login was successful.  Then we can set the label to the username, which is now a property for Login Form (see below)
         label1.Text = Form2.UserName;
    }
    else
    {
        //Login was cancelled
        //You must now implement logic to handle this case
    }
                
}
```

Now in the Login form you want to check login and return the dialog result to the MainForm.  DialogResult is, as the name suggests, the result of calling the LoginForm Dialog.

You will also need another click event for the cancel button.

```
public partial class login_Form : Form
{
    //username is changed to a property 
    public string Username { get; private set; }

    public login_Form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //The check remains as before.
        if (textBox_Login.Text == "Admin" && textBox_Password.Text == "123")
        {
            //If successful, we set the dialogresult, username and close this form.
            this.Username = textBox_Login.Text;
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            this.Close();
        }    
        else
        {
            //Otherwise we handle the error
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Username and/or Password Again!");
        }
    }

    //The new click event for the cancel button
    private void Button_Login_Cancel(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          //We set the dialogresult to cancel (could be anything else) and close
         this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
         this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will definitely try this out. For the Cancel button , I have already selected its DialogResult property to Cancel so it was working correctly as intended.